# Как добраться до элементов внутри GridView

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-linearlayout, calendar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке показана одна неделя и белым цветом выделен день.

Сама полоса - GridView, внутри которой c помощью Adapter(код нижу) выставленно 7 LinearLayout (дни недели).

В данный момент на GridView установлен слушатель, который и расскрашивает день недели по нажатию.

Задача состоит в том, что при открытии приложения сегодняшний день сразу помечался белым цветом (Без нажатия пользователя). Вопрос: как программно добраться до элемента внутри Grid View,чтобы раскрасить его?

**public class CalendarAdapter extends BaseAdapter {**

```
private Context             mContext;
private Date[]              mWeek;
private SimpleDateFormat    mFormatNumber;
private SimpleDateFormat    mFormatDay;
private LayoutInflater      mInflater;


public CalendarAdapter(Context _context, Date[] _week) {
        mContext        = _context;
        mWeek           = _week;
        mFormatNumber   = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
        mFormatDay      = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
        mInflater       = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}


//походу хранит в себе поля для ввода.
private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView     tvDay;
    public TextView     tvNumber;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mWeek.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mWeek[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}


//Здесь происходит формирование листа.
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    //если неделя заполняется первый раз выполняется
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView     = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day, null);
        holder          = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tvDay    = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_day);
        holder.tvNumber = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_number);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvDay.setText(mFormatDay.format(mWeek[position]));
    holder.tvNumber.setText(mFormatNumber.format(mWeek[position]));


    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: public boolean performItemClick (View view, int position, long id)

Пробовал использовать этот метод, чтобы инсценировать нажатие на элементе. Но никак не разберусь что в агрументы посылать, все время выдает ошибку.

Comment: к примеру, в зависимости от `position` - ставить `convertView` бекграунд.